# copy Azure sql database from server to another

Tags: sql, database, azure

I have faced an issue after executing this command

```
"CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF server1.Database1;"
```

For example, i have database1 from server1 and database2 from server2, after running the command above, now i can see both database1 and database2 in my both server1 and server2

if I update database1 in server1 it will also be update database1 in server2.

I just want to copy database1 to server2. I can delete the unwanted database but my worry is that the database will be deleted from both servers

appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think `as copy of` does a point-in-time copy.  If you want a live copy that stays up-to-date, then look into replication.

Comment: I followed the steps provided in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy under C
opy a SQL database to a different server section